# Loop resets the count and overwrites the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am extracting frames from a few videos in a directory using Open cv. While iterating through files, I am naming the frames obtained as frame0, frame1, and so on. But as the loop moves to the next video, it again starts naming the frames 0,1,2... and so all the old frames get overwritten.

Here is what I did:

```
#To make a list of paths to all files in dir
f=[]
for dirpath, subdir, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Files'):
for x in files:
    f.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))
```

Function to extract frames:

```
def extractFrames(pathIn, pathOut):

cap = cv.VideoCapture(pathIn)
count = 0

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        print('Read %d frame: ' % count, ret)
        cv.imwrite(os.path.join(pathOut, "frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)), 
frame)  
        count += 1
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then i execute the code:

```
pathOut=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frames'
def main():
    for i in f:
        extractFrames(i, pathOut)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

How do I rectify so that when the loop encounters the next video after creating n frames, it starts naming them n+1, n+2,.... instead of starting again from 0 and overwriting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `count` is initialized every time you call the function `extractFrames` - that is, once per file.

You need to put the initialization outside the function:

```
count = 0
def extractFrames(pathIn, pathOut):
  cap = cv.VideoCapture(pathIn)

  ...
```